# How can I situate specified <option> as default?

Tags: jquery

I have this html code:

```
<select name="0-gender" id="id_0-gender">
    <option value="0">Select gender:</option>
    <option value="1">Woman</option>
    <option value="2">Man</option>
</select>
```

`<option value="0">` is because of this:

```
$("#id_0-gender").prepend("<option value='0'></option>")
      $("#id_0-gender option[value='0']").text('Select gender:');
```

And when I open my page, as default I have "Woman", but need "Select gender". It is strange to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `option` to be selected by default:

```
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select gender:</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have this code:

```
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select gender:</option>
```

The "selected" part tells that option value should be selected by default.

Comment: Works good. After 11 minutes i give You that I accept answer.

Answer (score 1):

add

```
$(...).attr('selected','selected');
```

Only to option you want to have selected

Comment: But isn't this shorter:
$("#id_0-gender").prepend("<option value='0' selected='selected'></option>")

Answer (score 1):

you wrote:

```
$("#id_0-gender option[value='0']").text('Select gender:');
```

just do after that:

```
.prop("selected", true);
```

so, it will end like:

```
$("#id_0-gender option[value='0']")
    .text('Select gender:')
    .prop("selected", true);
```

---

from comments it just sounds like the original code is:

```
<select name="0-gender" id="id_0-gender">
    <option value="1">Woman</option>
    <option value="2">Man</option>
</select>
```

so, all you need to do is:

```
$("#id_0-gender")
    .append("<option value='0' selected='selected'>Select Gender</option>");
```

Comment: I do soemthing like this and it works: $("#id_0-gender").prepend("<option value='0' selected='selected'></option>")
In this example, shorter is better or something in my code looks ugly?

Comment: So, in your question **your code** has no gender text right? that's what you are assigning it, the original code has only 2 `<option>`'s and you are trying to append the **Select gender** part, is that right?

Comment: My code had text gender but only as one option to choose. Hiden option, because by default and as first option I had "Woman". But with this code that I wrote in comment above everything works good. But yes, original code has only 2 options and I needed to apend Select Gender.

Comment: then use just this line inside your `$(document).ready` block: `$("#id_0-gender").append("<option value='0' selected='selected'>Select Gender</option>");` as I added to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Better design perspective is use `RadioButtons` **group them**, set the selected value to **male**.Rarely few `Transgenders` come to visit websites

Comment: RadioButtons is better because need only one click. I am not expirienced designer. But if i have <select> to take user's birthdate it is good idea to composite this with RadioButtons?

Comment: @chris it's your choice, but radio buttons fit the purpose. DropDownList <select> is too much for what you ask. but again it's your app, your world you choose :) happy coding